# Antlr4: parse dot-ending float with double-dots

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to parse sentence with dot-ending float and double-dots ranging array, but cannot make it.

Here is my grammar file

```
grammar foo;

Digits
    :   [0-9]+
    ;

Real
    :   Digits* '.' Digits+
    |   Digits+ '.' Digits*
    ;

Range
    :   '..'
    ;

Whitespace
    :   [ \t]+
        -> skip
    ;

Newline
    :   (   '\r' '\n'?
        |   '\n'
        )
        -> skip
    ;

range
    :   Digits Range Digits
    ;
```

and(file named `foo.c`)

code 1:

```
1..2
```

code 2:

```
1 ..2
```

I use following to compile and test:

```
antlr4 foo.g4
javac foo*.java
grun foo range -gui foo.c
```

Code 1 will have error:

```
line 1:2 token recognition error at: '. '
line 1:0 extraneous input '1.' expecting Digits
line 1:5 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting '..'
```

However I can make it with code 2.

Adding extra space makes it correct, but I want to have a grammar that can parse code 1 without extra space.

Comment: I keep float that can ends with single dot: 1.

Answer (score 3):

That is how ANTLR's lexer works: it tries to match as much characters as possible. So the input `1..2` produces 2 `Real` tokens `1.` and `.2`, and not the 3 tokens `Digits`, `Range` and `Digits`.

To create 3 tokens, you will have to add [a predicate in your lexer grammar](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md#predicates-in-lexer-rules). Try something like this:

```
FLOAT
 : [0-9]+ '.' {_input.LA(1) != '.'}?
 | [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+
 ;

INT
 : [0-9]+
 ;

RANGE
 : '..'
 ;

SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
 ;
```

If I create a lexer from the rules above, and feed it the input `"1 2. .34 56..7 8.99999"`, I get the following tokens:

```
INT        '1'
FLOAT      '2.'
FLOAT      '.34'
INT        '56'
RANGE      '..'
INT        '7'
FLOAT      '8.99999'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `RANGE` definition **before** the `FLOAT` definition. That should cause the lexer to prioritize `'..'` over `'.'` and you won't need a predicate statement.